# Not able to access the methods of submodule in superproject

Tags: git, gitlab

I am not able to access the methods of submodule in superproject.

When I try to access it, that submodule refers only to `master` branch: its local branch does not change even after getting the `localbranch` changes in submodule.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the branch of a submodule, that means it will checkout a different commit than the one initially recorded by the parent project as "**[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**" (a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) of the main repo)

That means you need to go back to the parent repository, do a `git add`/`git commit` and push.

That way, another clone of the parent repository will see the right content in its associated submodule.